# Optimizing this dynamic programming solution

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, dynamic-programming

## The Problem:

You are given an array *m* of size *n*, where each value of *m* is composed of a weight *w*, and a percentage *p*.

`m = [m0, m1, m2, ... , mn] = [[m0w, m0p], [m1w, m1p], [m2w, m2p], ..., [mnw, mnp] ]`

So we'll represent this in python as a list of lists.

We are then trying to find the minimum value of this function:

```python
# chaima is so fuzzy how come?
def minimize_me(m):
    t = 0
    w = 1
    for i in range(len(m)):
        current = m[i]
        t += w * current[0]
        w *= current[1]
    return t
```

where the only thing we can change about *m* is its ordering. (i. e. rearrange the elements of *m* in any way) Additionally, this needs to complete in better than *O(n!)*.

## Brute Force Solution:

```python
import itertools
import sys

min_t = sys.maxint
min_permutation = None

for permutation in itertools.permutations(m):
    t = minimize_me(list(permutation), 0, 1)
    if t < min_t:
        min_t = t
        min_permutation = list(permutation)
```

## Ideas On How To Optimize:

the idea:

Instead of finding the best order, see if we can find a way to compare two given values in *m*, when we know the state of the problem.  (The code might explain this more clearly).  If I can build this using a bottom-up approach (so, starting from the end, assuming I have no optimal solution) and I can create an equation that can compare two values in *m* and say one is definitively better than the other, then I can construct an optimal solution, by using that new value, and comparing the next set of values of m.

the code:

```python
import itertools

def compare_m(a, b, v):
    a_first = b[0] + b[1] * (a[0] + a[1] * v)
    b_first = a[0] + a[1] * (b[0] + b[1] * v)

    if a_first > b_first:
        return a, a_first
    else:
        return b, b_first

best_ordering = []
v = 0

while len(m) > 1:
    best_pair_t = sys.maxint
    best_m = None

    for pair in itertools.combinations(m, 2):
        m, pair_t = compare_m(pair[0], pair[1], v)
        if pair_t < best_pair_t:
            best_pair_t = pair_t
            best_m = m

    best_ordering.append(best_m)
    m.remove(best_m)
    v = best_m[0] + best_m[1] * v

first = m[0]
best_ordering.append(first)
```

However, this is not working as intended.  The first value is always right, and roughly 60-75% of the time, the entire solution is optimal.  However, in some cases, it looks like the way I am changing the value *v* which then gets passed back into my compare is evaluating much higher than it should.  Here's the script I'm using to test against:

```python
import random

m = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    w = random.randint(1, 1023)
    p = random.uniform(0.01, 0.99)
    m.append([w, p])
```

Here's a particular test case demonstrating the error:

```python
m = [[493, 0.7181996086105675], [971, 0.19915848527349228], [736, 0.5184210526315789], [591, 0.5904761904761905], [467, 0.6161290322580645]]
```

optimal solution (just the indices) = [1, 4, 3, 2, 0]
my solution (just the indices) = [4, 3, 1, 2, 0]

It feels very close, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong.  Am I looking at this the wrong way?  Does this seem like it's on the right track?  Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "However, this is not working as intended."  Please explain.

Comment: Please explain the difference of your expected results and the current results. It'll be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't need any information about the current state of the algorithm to decide which elements of `m` are better. We can just sort the values using the following key:

```
def key(x):
    w, p = x
    return w/(1-p)

m.sort(key=key)
```

This requires explanation.

Suppose `(w1, p1)` is directly before `(w2, p2)` in the array. Then after processing these two items, `t` will be increased by an increment of `w * (w1 + p1*w2)` and `w` will be multiplied by a factor of `p1*p2`. If we switch the order of these items, `t` will be increased by an increment of `w * (w2 + p2*w1)` and `w` will be multiplied by a factor of `p1*p2`. Clearly, we should perform the switch if `(w1 + p1*w2) > (w2 + p2*w1)`, or equivalently after a little algebra, if `w1/(1-p1) > w2/(1-p2)`. If `w1/(1-p1) <= w2/(1-p2)`, we can say that these two elements of `m` are "correctly" ordered.

In the optimal ordering of `m`, there will be no pair of adjacent items worth switching; for any adjacent pair of `(w1, p1)` and `(w2, p2)`, we will have `w1/(1-p1) <= w2/(1-p2)`. Since the relation of having `w1/(1-p1) <= w2/(1-p2)` is the natural total ordering on the w/(1-p) values, the fact that `w1/(1-p1) <= w2/(1-p2)` holds for any pair of adjacent items means that the list is sorted by the w/(1-p) values.

---

Your attempted solution fails because it only considers what a pair of elements would do to the value of the tail of the array. It doesn't consider the fact that rather than using a low-p element now, to minimize the value of the tail, it might be better to save it for later, so you can apply that multiplier to more elements of m.

---

Note that the proof of our algorithm's validity relies on all `p` values being at least 0 and strictly less than 1. If p is 1, we can't divide by 1-p, and if p is greater than 1, dividing by 1-p reverses the direction of the inequality. These problems can be resolved using a comparator or a more sophisticated sort key. If p is less than 0, then `w` can switch sign, which reverses the logic of what items should be switched. Then we *do* need to know about the current state of the algorithm to decide which elements are better, and I'm not sure what to do then.